# What is the appropriate Google service to securely call API functions in a mobile app?

Tags: android, authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth, backend

I'm making an Android app that uses some Google Cloud APIs that require OAuth2. Ideally, I would like to use Google Cloud for my backend server in some capacity. I read very carefully over these articles (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app) and I have the code working to get an authorization code from Google, but I am completely stuck on the part where I exchange the auth code for a token using my backend server. It definitely doesn't help that I haven't created a backend server before, and I have no clue what kind of service to use for that. I looked at API Gateway, App Engine, and Compute Engine, but none of those seem to make any sense, and even if I knew what service to use, I'd probably be completely lost with what to do with them. Does anybody have any advice on which services to use or what to do to authenticate using a backend server? I would definitely prefer to use a Google Cloud service for this, mainly for convenience, because I'm already going to be using a lot of other Google services such as Firebase and Calendar. Thanks!

Edit: What I'm mainly trying to do is call the endpoint https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token and obtain an access token for the APIs, and I'm thinking that should be done with the backend server. Any guidance on what services to use is very much appreciated (i.e. App Engine, API Gateway, APIGee, etc.). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Firebase offers several authentication solutions, they are really well documented and many examples available.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concern with that first link at least is putting the values directly in the application (e.g. where it says to put the Twitter consumer key and consumer secret directly in strings.xml). Is this good practice, or should it be avoided? I'm thinking if it's bad practice, then that's why I should use the backend server.